# What make of RAM would compliment my existing one?

Tags: motherboard, memory

I want to upgrade my work PC's memory but I'm not sure what to order. It's running Ubuntu 16.04 and has a Fujitsu D3128-A2 mainboard. Four out of eight memory slots are occupied. This is the output of `sudo lshw -short -C memory`:

[image: OS memory information]

Are these information enough to select new RAM? I'd like to add another 32GB (which the mainboard can handle according to the German manual). I have not been able to find the current make of memory in a shop, which is SK hynix H5TQ4G83AFR. 
E: As pointed out in the comments, that seems to be the name of the chip, while this is apparently the correct ID for the whole thing:

[image]

Comment: Hynix just makes the memory chips, I need information about the manufacturer of the actual RAM kit you bought to be able to help. Even if you got a different kit with the same chips, the PCB can vary as can standards for timing, voltage, clock speed, etc. Usually the physical RAM stick has a long model number / designation printed onto a sticker. Your best bet is to get RAM that matches the model number of your current kit, or to buy an entire new set. Mixing RAM kits introduces too much risk of system instability to be advisable.

Comment: @jcam3 Right, so I took one bar out and there's a sticker with more info. It seems like Hynix did indeed manufacture the whole thing, at least there's no other indications (see above). There's similar ones on eBay but haven't found the exact one yet

Comment: Normally I'd recommend going to Crucial's website and using their memory finder to pick a guaranteed-compatible upgrade, but they appear to be out of stock on the memory you need.

Comment: @Mark I ended up asking for a recommendation/quote from a German supplier. They offered me some memory that's guaranteed to work with mine, but it's OEM stuff with their own label on it. Maybe I can read the actual make when it's arrived. Thanks!